How would I accomplish rendering data from another function on the first render?
I need to fetch all the user libraries from the backend and display them in a dropdown menu.
I created a separate JS file to fetch the libraries from the backend, and then called that JS file in my main library TSX page.
This was the error that occurred:

Type 'Promise<{ label: string; value: string; }[] | undefined>' is
missing the following properties from type '({ label: any; } & {
value: any; })[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 35 more

fetch_libraries JS file (Fetches the libraries from the backend):
import { getItemFor } from './async_store';
import { supabase } from './supabase';

// Supabase is the backend I'm using.

export default async function libraries_fetch () {
    
    // Creating empty array and fetching user email
    const libraries = [];
    const email = await getItemFor("email");

    // Fetching libraries from the database
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from('pdfs')
        .list(`${email}/books`);
    
    // Adding libraries to the libraries array
    if (data != null) {
        for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
            libraries.push({label: data[x].name, value: x.toString()})
        }
        return (libraries);
    };
};

My libraries main page. I'm trying to get a dropdown menu on the header's top right corner.
// Expo 
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';

// App Backend
import { styles } from '../../assets/stylers';
import Colors from '@/constants/Colors';
import fetch_libraries from '../backend/fetch_libraries';

// React
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function library() {
  const data = fetch_libraries()
  return (
    <View>
      <Stack.Screen 
        options={{
          headerStyle: styles.HeaderStyle, 
          headerTitleStyle: styles.HeaderTextStyle, 
          headerRight:(() => <Dropdown
            style={styles.libraryDropDownScroll}
            itemContainerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownItem}
            containerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownContainer}
            data={data} // This is where the error is occurring
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder='Main'
            onChange={item => {}}
            renderRightIcon={() => (<Ionicons
              name="arrow-down" 
              size={20} 
              color={Colors.black} 
              style={styles.closeIconStyle}
            />)}
          />)}
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

I was experimenting around with useState and useEffect but I can't seem to get the desired outcome. If I use useState, it doesn't update the libraries list in the first render, so the array is still blank when the app opens.

As @monvanCe suggests, using await will help.
However, it would be better to use a custom hook which will fetch this data when the component mounts and return the result.
For instance:
export const useData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  // fetch data here and set it in state
  }, []);
  
  return data;
}

You can then call this hook in your header component to get the data.
import {useData} from '...'


const dropDownData = useData();
return (
...
  <Dropdown 
    data={dropDownData}
  />
...
)


Thanks for the answer. I was curious though, what's stopping the useData function from returning data before the state is set? Won't the function return [] at first render? Or will the useEffect always run before the return statement?

@AnirudhKuppili If you add console logs before the return statement and the useEffect, you will see that useData does indeed return [] the first time, then the function within useEffect updates the state with the data fetched asynchronously, which causes the parent component (Header) to re-render and invoke the useData hook again. This time, the useEffect will be bypassed and the value stored in the data state variable will be returned. To summarize: Invoke useData --> return [] --> run effect --> update state --> invoke useData --> return fetched data stored in state

You should use await before fetch_libraries():
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch_libraries()
        setData(response)
    }

    fetchData()
},[])

